# sqlite returns no results

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm under a wall. I have a very simple method

```
public List<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold> findAll() {
    List<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold> result = new ArrayList<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(MainHelper.TABLE_FOOTHOLD, FOOTHOLD_FIELDS, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold foothold = this.mapToObject(cursor);
        result.add(foothold);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;

}
```

It should return every record from table but it returns 0 (zero). I don't know why. I've debugged whole process the query looks ok. What is funny when I copy the query that is invoked and run it manualy on DB i receive the results. But when I do it from Android level I return nothing. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: to debug db stuff use `DatabaseUtils` and (for example) its static method `dumpCursor()`, the question is why do you want to iterate over the `Cursor` at all?

Comment: @pskink beucase I want a collection of my objects. But this is not the problem because cursor contains no results.

Comment: did you make sure calling `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` ?

Comment: @pskink nope, not this time :) I need to convert to my object and use it global application configuration. But if you have some interesting article about why shouldn't I iterate the cursor the please share. Btw. dumpCursor is very handly tool. Thank you for it.

Comment: so is it really an empty `Cursor`? maybe `MainHelper.TABLE_FOOTHOLD` points to an empty table in your db? maybe try for testing `rawQuery` to figure out whats wrong? BTW better use: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...` pattern

Comment: @pskink there was a bug in application not in this method but I found it after you shown the dumpCursor method so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code pattern for a cursor:

```
public List<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold> findAll() {
    List<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold> result = new ArrayList<com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(MainHelper.TABLE_FOOTHOLD, FOOTHOLD_FIELDS, null, null, null, null, null);
    com.fixus.portals.model.Foothold foothold = this.mapToObject(cursor);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
        result.add(foothold);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }else{
        //Your code for no data
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;

}
```

And make sure that your table is not empty.

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...` pattern is the most commonly used, grep the AOSP code and you will see

Comment: @Santiago why this pattern is better ?

Comment: @Fixus its not better, use simple `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...`

Comment: @Fixus you need to confirm if there are data in cursor with boolean result moveToFirst() and add result to list with moveToNext, you can use do while or while, doesn't matter., in your code you don't check if there are data in cursor.